# Couldn't find User with 'id'=#<User:0x007f88b1d4f9e0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, parameters

I'm having this issue and it looks like I am traversing the params hash correctly in the create method of the controller, but something is wrong.

`user_friendships_controller.rb`

```
class UserFriendshipsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]

def new
    if params[:friend_id]
        @friend = User.find(params[:friend_id])
        @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.new(friend: @friend)
    else
        flash[:error] = "Friend required"
    end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render file: 'public/404', status: :not_found
end

def create
    if params[:user_friendship] && params[:user_friendship].has_key?(:friend_id)
        @friend = User.find(params[:user_friendship][:friend_id])
        @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.new(friend: @friend)
        @user_friendship.save
        flash[:success] = "You are now friends with #{@friend.first_name.titleize}!"
        redirect_to user_path(@friend)
    else
        flash[:error] = "Friend required"
        @user_friendship = current_user.user_friendships.new(friend: @friend)
    end
end
end
```

The error is on line 17 @friend = User.find(params[:user_friendship][:friend_id])

```
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"p8hBlY50rLH4477juS4tAoo2aWiEaUD6oSzuCzxPTiU=",
 "user_friendship"=>{"friend_id"=>"#<User:0x007f88b1d4f9e0>"},
 "commit"=>"Yes,
 Add Friend"}
```

Here is the form pointing to the create method

```
<%= form_for @user_friendship, method: :post do |f| %>
    <div class="form form-actions">
        <%= f.hidden_field :friend_id, value: @friend %>
        <%= submit_tag "Yes, Add Friend", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        <%= link_to "Cancel", user_path(@friend), class: 'btn btn-danger'  %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The issue is on whatever is submitting; you're passing to `to_s` of a user instead of the user ID.

Comment: Oh, good catch. I don't know why that user object is wrapped in a string

Comment: Please post the `form` code.

Comment: `<%= form_for @user_friendship, method: :post do |f| %>
  
<div class="form form-actions">
   <%= f.hidden_field :friend_id, value: @friend %>
   <%= submit_tag "Yes, Add Friend", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
   <%= link_to "Cancel", user_path(@friend), class: 'btn btn-danger'  %>
  </div>
 <% end %>`

Comment: Oh, I mean add it in the question.

Comment: And you should use `@friend.id` here `<%= f.hidden_field :friend_id, value: @friend %>`

Comment: Sorry, added it to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change this line

```
<%= f.hidden_field :friend_id, value: @friend %>
```

to

```
<%= f.hidden_field :friend_id, value: @friend.id %>
```

Comment: This was it. Just adding the id to @friend. Gracias